# access command line data in Excel VBA fails

Tags: excel, vba

I need to access the command line parameters in an Excel VBA macro, and found many variations but only one that worked with Excel-2010, seems that the API has changed over time. I tried this code I found "[out there](http://www.dmcinfo.com/Blog/articleType/ArticleView/articleId/247/Read-Command-Line-Parameters-from-VBA.aspx)":

```
  Dim pCmdLine As Long     ' Pointer to the Comand-line string
  Dim strCmdLine As String ' Command line string
  Dim CmdLine As String    ' Command line string

  ' Get the pointer to the command line string
   pCmdLine = GetCommandLineA

   ' Fill the string with zeros
   '    (300 characters for command line seems to be enough)
   strCmdLine = String$(300, vbNullChar)

   ' Copy from the pointer to VBA-style string
   lstrcpynA strCmdLine, pCmdLine, Len(strCmdLine)

   ' At this point we got the string,
   '     now skip the rest of it filled with 0 characters.
   CmdLine = Left(strCmdLine, InStr(1, strCmdLine, vbNullChar) - 1)

  MsgBox "Length of the command line = " & Len(CmdLine) '' Debug
  MsgBox "Command Line:: " & CmdLine '' Debug
```

Which I put into the Auto_open macro of a spreadsheet. If I try this call:

```
start excel TestMacro.xlsm /e/abcd/xyz
```

It seems to generally work and the macro reports:

```
Command line = " C:/.../excel.exe TestMacro.xlsm"
```

So I get the invocation part, but the parameters are lost.

**Partial Solution:**
I find that if I change the invocation to:

```
   start excel  /e/abcd/xyz TestMacro.xlsm
```

It works, except the parsing code has to be changed to ignore the file name which is not at the end, and also this form doesn't seem to allow any blanks in any parameter, even if quoted. The system seems to interpret them as file names for a target excel file and give an error. For example:

```
start excel /e/abc/"my sheet"/ TestMacro.xlsm
```

gives the error:

```
file 'sheet"/.xlsx' not found
```

Although after the spurious startup error, the intended sheet does open and get teh entire line to work with.

Comment: What do you really want to do? Do you want to open an excel workbook? If you can share with us your ultimate goal and the UI you are currently using, that's better. What's the reason you need to use commandlines?

Comment: I don't think all the details are too relevant, but I want to invoke it like this: "start excel mySheet.xlsm /e/abc/def", and have the startup macro get the parameters to operate on.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: Yes, sort-of - as described above. I only use one argument with the /e/ format, and use a URL like parameter encoding for putting multiple values into that one argument. For blanks I just used "\\". There may be other better ways, you might ask in an excel forum.